# Branch links in push notification Android

Tags: android, push-notification, branch, branch.io

I have successfully integrated branch in my android app but when i send the branch link in the push notification and following the steps mentioned in their docs my `JSONObject`(i.e referringparams) is getting to be empty. I am using mixpanel for push notification.

The steps I followed for integrating branch link in push notification are as followed:

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, myRespective.class);
intent.putExtra("branch", myBranchCustomLink);
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =  PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
                   0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Please tell me where i am going wrong. The issue is only with push notifications. When I click on the branch links its redirecting currently to the page I require.

Comment: Alex from Branch.io here: you may want to [submit a ticket](https://support.branch.io/support/tickets/new) to our Integrations team to help debug this issue!

Answer (score 0):

When the app is in the foreground you need to add

```
intent.putExtra("branch_force_new_session",true);
```

The code looks like this:

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, BaseActivity.class);
  intent.putExtra("branch", branchLink);
  intent.putExtra("branch_force_new_session",true);
  pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```